# How do I control exposure in aperture priority mode?

Tags: exposure, camera-controls, aperture-priority

I am a beginner, shooting in aperture priority mode.

So I set the aperture I want for the scenery. Next thing is: how to control the exposure? I guess camera calculates everything else?

- I can change the ISO, but that requires some button pressing. My ISO is set to some Auto mode, and usually I dont change it during one period of the day.
- I can go ahead and control the shutter speed, leaving camera to calc the ISO.
- Set the ISO as well depending on environment brightness, and let the camera calc the SS?

My camera is a Fuji X100T.

Comment: What kind of camera are you using? Cameras generally compensate the ISO/Shutter speed in aperture priority mode to achieve a balanced exposure.

Comment: Updated the question with camera model.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is exposure compensation?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4578/what-is-exposure-compensation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Assuming you're shooting in aperture priority mode, fiddling with the shutter speed or ISO actually won't change much.

The exposure is automatically calculated by the camera for you and it tries to estimate what shutter speed + ISO will give you a correctly exposed photo. Assuming you're not happy with what you see after you take a photo using your chosen aperture, your next step if you stay in that mode is to tweak the exposure compensation value (EV) upwards if you want brighter photos, or downwards if you want darker photos. If you change the ISO, what will happen if you don't change the EV value is the camera will most likely change the shutter speed to compensate for you changing the ISO, and vice versa, if you change the shutter speed, then the camera will tweak the ISO. If you're manually setting all three, well that's no longer really aperture priority mode. Anyways, onto the messing with the EV settings.

I don't own that camera, so I can't give you an exact step by step, but a quick search tells me that the camera has EV compensation, which means you can change the value. It will probably look something like this, and it will probably pop up somewhere on your display when you take photos.

```
-3 | | | -2 | | | -1 | | | 0 | | | 1 | | | 2 | | | 3
                           ^
```

The ^ shows you what the camera is aiming for, and you should be able to tweak that higher or lower. For example

```
-3 | | | -2 | | | -1 | | | 0 | | | 1 | | | 2 | | | 3
                                   ^
```

will make your photo brighter, so your ISO will go up or shutter speed down, or a mixture of both.

```
-3 | | | -2 | | | -1 | | | 0 | | | 1 | | | 2 | | | 3
                   ^
```

will make your photo darker, and your ISO will go down or shutter speed up, or a mixture of both.

Answer (score 4):

Aperture Priority is an Automatic mode. In all Auto Modes the camera will automatically set what it thinks is the correct exposure. Changing the Aperture, Shutter or ISO or  will not change the exposure if any one of them are in "A" or "Auto".

If you want additional control, you must use the Exposure Compensation dial to lighten or darken the photo.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh wow, that is one classic control interface!

Comment: Yes the Fuji X100T has "Retro" controls. It has has an aperture ring on the lens with the various apertures and also an "A" position.http://i2.photobucket.com/albums/y17/msowsun/photo%20stuff/photo16/X100T_Top_Down.jpg

Comment: Is it bad that I'm now googling pictures of a camera? That is just gorgeous!